# WebGL warning: drawArraysInstanced: TEXTURE_2D at unit 0 is incomplete: The dimensions of `level_base` are not all positive

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webgl

I am trying to use a texture on webgl.

the code for importing this image is:

```
var image = new Image();  // Create the image object
image.onload = loadTexture(gl, n, texture, u_Sampler, image);
image.crossOrigin = "";
image.src = 'beacon.png';

function loadTexture(gl, n, texture, u_Sampler, image) {
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, 1); // Flip the image's y axis
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  gl.uniform1i(u_Sampler, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   // Clear <canvas>
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, n); // Draw the rectangle
}
```

including the line image.crossOrigin = "" stops the CORS error from showing in firefox (but not in chrome?) but firefox does give three other warnings when the page tries to load:

```
unreachable code after return statement
```

^ this happens even when all return statements are removed from the program.

```
Exceeded 16 live WebGL contexts for this principal, losing the least recently used one.
```

and

```
WebGL warning: drawArraysInstanced: TEXTURE_2D at unit 0 is incomplete: The dimensions of `level_base` are not all positive.
```

the texture doesn't load, the canvas appears as a black square

Comment: Where is the image and how are you running the code? Is the texture on the same computer as the page? Are you running [with a local web server](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-setup-and-installation.html) or directly from your hard drive?

Comment: the image is stored in the same directory as the javascript file. I have tried running a server and changing the image src to "localhost:8000/beacon.png", and it doesnt make any difference

Answer (score 1):

You generally need to [run a server for images in WebGL](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-setup-and-installation.html).

If your image is on the same domain then you should **not** set `crossDomain`. If, it's on a different domain then you should, though the server still needs to give permission to use the image. See [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html)

Otherwise there's a few issues with the code

1. It's not actually setting a onload callback on the image

   this line

   ```
   image.onload = loadTexture(gl, n, texture, u_Sampler, image);
   ```

   is functionally equivilent to

   ```
   const result = loadTexture(gl, n, texture, u_Sampler, image);
   image.onload = result;
   ```

   The line needs to be something like this so that loadTexture
   is called after the image loads, not before

   ```
   image.onload = () => loadTexture(gl, n, texture, u_Sampler, image);
   ```
2. You might need to set wrapping to `CLAMP_TO_EDGE`

   ```
   // these two lines needed in WebGL1 but not WebGL2 if the image is not
   // power of 2 in both dimension
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   ```

   Your title suggests your using WebGL2 by mentioning `drawAraysInstanced` but the code you posted does not use that and you didn't tag [webgl2](/questions/tagged/webgl2)

```js
const vs = `
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
  gl_PointSize = 100.0;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_Sampler;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Sampler, gl_PointCoord.xy);
}
`;

const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const prg = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
const u_Sampler = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, 'u_Sampler');

gl.useProgram(prg);

const texture = gl.createTexture();
const n = 4;

var image = new Image();  // Create the image object
image.onload = () => loadTexture(gl, n, texture, u_Sampler, image);
image.crossOrigin = "";
image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png';

function loadTexture(gl, n, texture, u_Sampler, image) {
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, 1); // Flip the image's y axis
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
// these two lines needed in WebGL1 but not WebGL2
// if the image is not power-of-2 in both dimensions
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  gl.uniform1i(u_Sampler, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   // Clear <canvas>
  //gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, n); // Draw the rectangle
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

As for the other warnings.

> unreachable code after return statement

You didn't post enough code to find that warning but it means exactly what it says. For example

```
function foo() {
  return;
  console.log('here');
}
```

will generate that warning

> Exceeded 16 live WebGL contexts for this principal, losing the least recently used one.

This is arguably [a bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1633311) though if the code is bad (like if it's creating canvases and contexts in a loop) then there are legit cases for this warning . In general though it comes up reloading a page 17 times like during web development. Hopefully Firefox will fix it so it only shows the warning when it's legit.

Comment: "Hopefully Firefox will fix it so it only shows the warning when it's legit." I'm fairly certain that the warning is legit and that they really don't close the context on reload. My test show that vram isn't freed on page reload, instead the tab has to be closed and reopened.

Comment: It's not legit for a user to have to care about pages that are no longer loaded.  A warning for something you can't fix is not legit. it's not useful to say "oh hey! this thing happened but guess what, there is nothing you could have done differently to prevent the warning". If they aren't freeing vram that's just yet another bug.